# How to write values of a dict to an empty (new) column in openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, openpyxl

Given a dict `aNewDictEachDay` and a worksheet `ws`=`openpyxl.load_workbook('roi.xlsx', data_only=True).worksheets[0]`.

Column 0 (A) of `ws` contains keys. All other columns are empty (for now). Each day, I want to load the workbook, and update `ws` thus:

1. Write the current date to the top cell in a *new* column
2. For each value in `aNewDictEachDay.values()`:

   - if its key is already in Column 0:

     - write that value in its appropriate
       place (row) in the new column
   - else:

     - add the key as a new row in Column0
     - write that value in its appropriate
       place (row) in the new column

I'm usually using openpyxl with spreadsheets that already have populated columns. With the spreadsheet currently only having a single column, the notion of other columns (in this case, B) would appear not to exist:

```
In [238]: ws.columns
Out[238]: ((<Cell Sheet1.A1>, <Cell Sheet1.A2),)
```

If a column already exists, the values of its various cells can be overwritten readily with `openpyxl`. But how is it done when the column is yet to exist?

After:

```
for row in aNewDictEachDay.values():
```

How do I employ `ws.append()` in the right fashion?

Comment: openpyxl uses 1-indexing.

Comment: Why 1-indexing for assignment using ws.cell(), but 0-indexing for accessing cells? ws.columns[0][0] (not ws.columns[1][1] ) gives **<Cell Sheet1.A1>**

Comment: Worksheets are dedicated data structures and 1-indexing was chosen to reduce "off by 1" errors when switching between R1C1 and A1 notation.

The rows and columns properties on the other hand are straight Python lists (or generators) which are 0-indexed.

Comment: @CharlieClark OK. Great library, and great info at the readthedocs site. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add an individual cell it's best to use `ws.cell()` which will allow you to specify the row and column index.

To insert a "B" column:

```
for i in range(11, 1):
    ws.cell(row=i, column=2).value = i
```